# Searching through parent array and print child array name if match is found

Tags: php, arrays

I have this parent array called `$sourcearray` that will have many child arrays. I am trying to right and if else statement to search through all of the parent array to see if this id number matches up with any of the values in the child arrays. If the id number matches up then print the child array's name.

Here is the code I have so far. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sourcearray = array(

$AdvMag1 = array(
    '2422',
    '2423',
    '2441',
    '2495',
    '2466',
),

$AdvEmail = array(
    '2425',
    '701i0000001FfEL',
    '701i0000001Fl78',
),
);

if (in_array($id,$sourcearray)) {
   print childarray();
}
else{
     echo"Search-Other";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sourcearray = array(
  "AdvMag1" => array(
      '2422',
      '2423',
      '2441',
      '2495',
      '2466'
  ),      
  "AdvEmail" => array(
      '2425',
      '701i0000001FfEL',
      '701i0000001Fl78'
  )
);

foreach($sourcearray as $name => $childarray) {
    if(in_array($id,$childarray)) {
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "Search-Other";
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I did have to add a return at the end of it to make it work properly, but other than that it worked great! Above is the final code I used!

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thank you!!

I did notice I needed to add a return at the end of the for each statement to make it work properly.
Final code:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$sourcearray = array(
  "AdvMag1" => array(
      '2422',
      '2423',
      '2441',
      '2495',
      '2466'
  ),      
  "AdvEmail" => array(
      '2425',
      '701i0000001FfEL',
      '701i0000001Fl78'
  )
);

foreach($sourcearray as $name => $childarray) {
    if(in_array($id,$childarray)) {
        echo $name;
    } else {
        echo "Search-Other";
    }
    return;
}
```